# mysql - query three tables

Tags: mysql, database, join, relational

I have a relational database with three tables. The first containts id's that relate to the second. The second contains id's that relate to the third. The third contains the results I am after.

Is it possible with a single query to query an id in the first table which gives all results from the third table that relate to it?

Sorry I am new to mySQL.

Comment: If you give a table structure, we can give you more specific answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Mysql Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Try this

```
select * from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.t2ref = t2.id
join table3 t3 on t2.t3ref = t3.id
```

Add a where clause to search for certain rows in table1

```
where t1.field = 'value'
```

Answer (score 5):

yes

```
SELECT t3.* 
  FROM t1, t2, t3
  WHERE t1.id = t2.id
    AND t2.otherid = t3.id
    AND t1.id = XXXX
```

Comment: Thank you... I tried it and it worked perfectly... I also tried Peter Lindqvist's approach (using joins). I heard JOIN's are expensive. Your solution came out at 0.0004 second as apposed to 0.0005 seconds. At the moment I hardly have any data though. Which is likely to be more efficient?

Comment: the mysql query optimizer will transform this query also into a join

Comment: i think that the difference you experience is actually not significant. If you get slow queries you need to examine your index structure. Joins with 3 tables and the proper indexing will normally not become slow.

Answer (score 3):

you want to use a join:

```
   SELECT `t3`.`id`
     FROM `table3` `t3`
LEFT JOIN `table2` `t2`
       ON `t3`.`foreign_id` = `t2`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `table1` `t1`
       ON `t2`.`foreign_id` = `t1`.`id`
    WHERE `t1`.`id` = 'some_id'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) command to link your tables to oneantother.

Additionally I'd recommend [this tutorial](http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php) by Keith Brown.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a **[join](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp)**. There is a lot of [tutorials](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Join/JOINthreetableswithconditions.htm) about this and [various ways](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp) of doing it.