# How can I insert data into two mysql tables at once using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mySQL - Insert into three tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723232/mysql-insert-into-three-tables)

I want to know if I can insert data into two tables using one query in PHP/MySQL?

If it's possible, can I see an example?

Comment: That's what triggers are for.

Comment: @Steve-o: actually - triggers aren't for this *specifically* ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Mysql [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) syntax accepts one and only one table as a target

Comment: @ajreal: just because it doesn't, by definition. Can you show us how to insert into 3 different tables that have no any relations **using triggers**?

Comment: Thank you! Now I can move forward without the though that there might be a possibility. :P (maybe later down the road ;))

Answer (score 2):

> **using one query**

**no**

Comment: It wasn't that easy to have the answer longer than 30 chars, was it? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: exactly. I have submitted it 4 times and after the last one I had to fill up captcha :(

Comment: @ajreal: NO not without mysqli

Comment: @genesis φ: it is not possible using any driver, because of OP asked: "into two tables **using one query**"

Comment: @ajreal: waiting for proof your words, challenge description is at my answer comments. If you have any questions about challenge - ask.

Comment: @ajreal: calling storing procedure **is not** literally a query. This discussion becomes something about terminology war.

Answer (score 0):

Using one query! I don't think so.

However, I believe that the most appropriate methodology is to utilise transactions. Using transactions, you assure to have data inserted in more than one table (successfully), otherwise any changes are rolled back. That is, either persist all changes or do nothing at all.