# Insert into 2 table and set both foreign key auto increment

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with two tables. When a user posts an article, it will be inserted into both tables, (2 queries in one file)

I use `post_id` as `foreign key`, both tables `post_id` auto increment. Will foreign keys be messed up? For example if users A and B query the database at the same time.

Table 1

```
post_id user...
1       A
2       B
```

Table 2

```
post_id content...
1       A
2       B
```

Comment: You can only have 1 auto increment field in a table. use Joins instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you can't have auto increment on both tables.

Usually, what you do is `insert` in `table 1`, get the `ID` of the just inserted row.

Then you use this `ID`, to `insert` in `table 2` which references `table 1`.

See: **mysqli::$insert_id** at

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

**Example:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1(user,whatever) VALUES ('A','something')";
$mysqli->query($query);

printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);

$query = "INSERT INTO table2(post_id,content) VALUES ($mysqli->insert_id,'This is content')";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

Comment: so I have to use last insert id and query after

Comment: Exactly... and not have autoincrement on the second table.

Comment: Better yet, you can also use a stored procedure which is described here fitting your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1723325/1688441

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this using a stored procedure based on: stackoverflow.com/a/1723325/1688441

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE new_post_with_content(
  user_id CHAR(5), content_text CHAR(100)
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
   INSERT INTO table1 (user) 
     VALUES(user_id);

   INSERT INTO table2 (post_id, content) 
     VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), content_text);
COMMIT;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

And you call it like so:

```
CALL new_engineer_with_task('A','This is the content');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use table1 as user table and second with posts?

```
users
user_id(autoinc)    username
1                   A
2                   B
3                   C

posts
post_id(autoinc)   user_id       posts_text
1                  2             text
2                  1             other text
```