# Join three tables in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have three tables like this:

**Person**

```
id | name   | location
-----------------------
 1 | ABC    | Location1
 2 | XYZ    | Location2
```

**Contact**

```
id | type    | contact
---------------------------
 1 | website | abc.com
 2 | email   | abc@abc.com
 3 | website | xyz.com
 4 | email   | xyz@xyz.com
```

**PersonContact**

```
Person_id | Contact_id
-----------------------
    1     |    1
    1     |    2
    2     |    3
    2     |    4
```

**I want to get result something like this:**

```
id | name | website | email
----------------------------------
 1 | ABC  | abc.com | abc@abc.com
 2 | XYZ  | xyz.com | xyz@xyz.com
```

Comment: What have you *tried*? What worked? What didn't?

Comment: What have you tried?  This is really easy to do..I would feel bad if I just gave you the answer straight up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql - query three tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715955/mysql-query-three-tables)

Comment: I'm not sure this is as obvious as you guys are making it out to be. He basically wants to transpose rows into columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but here is an easy one for MySQL

```
SELECT
   p.id,
   p.name,
   MAX(IF(c.type = 'website', c.contact, NULL)) AS 'website',
   MAX(IF(c.type = 'email', c.contact, NULL)) AS 'email'
FROM
   Person p INNER JOIN
   PersonContact pc ON p.id = pc.Person_ID INNER JOIN
   Contact c ON pc.contact_id = c.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting how complex that query would be without using if statements. It's actually one left join per column! Great work @Ben!

```
select p.id, p.name, max(website) as website, max(email) as email from person p
join personContact pc on p.id = pc.person_id
join contact c on pc.contact_id = c.id
left join (
  select c.id as cid, c.contact as website from personContact pc
  join contact c on pc.contact_id = c.id
  where c.type = 'website'
) as WebsiteCol
on c.id = WebsiteCol.cid
left join (
  select c.id as cid, c.contact as email from personContact pc
  join contact c on pc.contact_id = c.id
  where c.type = 'email'
) as EmailCol
on c.id = EmailCol.cid
group by p.id, p.name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, c.contact FROM Person p, PersonContact pc , Contact c WHERE p.id = pc.Person_id AND pc.Contact_id= c.id
```

Comment: that doesn't give the result that the OP requested